# Reverse order of firstname and lastname in SQL column

Tags: sql

I have a column in a SQL database in the format initial space surname, e.g. "J Smith", and I'd like it to be "Smith J".  What is the most efficient way of doing this using T-SQL?  The table has many millions of records.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the substring formulas, but use them to avoid having to use them ever again:

```
ALTER TABLE SillyTable ADD FirstInitial char(1), LastName varchar(50);

INSERT INTO SillyTable(FirstInitial, LastName) 
SELECT SUBSTRING(NameColumn, 1, 1), SUBSTRING(NameColumn, 3, LEN(NameColumn) - 2)
FROM SillyTable;

SELECT LastName + ' ' + FirstInitial AS WhatMyBossWantsToday FROM SillyTable;
```

Comment: Because tomorrow the boss will change his mind again and want a comma between the last name and the initial.

Comment: It's a better design over-all to store the first initial and last name in separate columns, because they are separate independent pieces of data.  SQL sorting and indexing can work on two columns just as well as one column, but having data in two columns gives you more flexibility.

Comment: Vincent, it's not *just* a matter of changing the table, it's also a matter of changing every piece of software that reads or writes from the table.  There could be thousands of lines of code that need to be modified.

Comment: "Different pieces of data" who said this? Tradition to store the name and surname into two columns are not the "domain rule" it's just a technical solution of problem how to index both words.

Comment: If somebody wants to reverse the order of initial and surname, that's conclusive evidence that these are separate fields.

Comment: @David Grayson: Usually, when there are thousands of line of code that need to be modified, you don't change the content of a table just for the fun of it. I'm not going to argue more, because we don't know anything about what's going on.

Comment: @Narveson: you're right, but if they didn't think about it during DB design, it might be quite time(=money) consuming to correct it now.<br>@Vincent: yea, without more info there is no way to tell which way is best in this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the column is indeed 1 character followed by a space followed by the name...

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(x,3,255)+' '+SUBSTRING(x,1,1)
```